# Setting PK value to what API returns in database instead of generating DB value

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, unique, primary-key

I have an odd question/situation with whom I've never had encountered before...

So I'm using an API of a small website which provides me informations of their transactions from their DB.

And on the other hand I have my DB which basically looks like this:

```
create table API_Transactions
(
TransactionId int not null -- this is the part on which I have the question
TransactionDate datetime not null,
-- and some other data here...
)
```

So as you can see I have my PK in my API_Transactions table which, on normal occasions I would regularely set to be DB auto generated ( identity(1,1) statement)...

But the tricky part here is that the values that this API returns of their TransactionID is always unique, so I  was thinking of doing the following (if its possible/smart or wise):

Using this API TransactionID value as my own PK value to ensure that I don't have 1 extra column more in my DB) like this:

```
create table API_Transactions
    (
    TransactionId int not null identity(1,1) primary key-- this is the part on which I have the question
    API_TranactionID int not null -- id of transaction from the API...
    TransactionDate datetime not null,

    -- and some other data here...
    )
```

This way I would ensure to avoid creating 1 extra column in my DB and save some space (perhaps even performance improvement in later use of DB?)..

If this is doable, what would be the best way of doing this? Which data type would I use then for my PK and how would I set it ?

Can someone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So search the internet for the term "premature optimization". And I'll disagree with @Pawel. There is no basis for making the claim that "performance will be better". What "performance" are we talking about? It is premature to assume that insert performance is the most significant measure (and ignore all other measures). And I see a common mistake - assuming that the primary key is also the clustered key.

I will agree that disk space is of no concern at this point. Until you **absolutely** know that you do not need the key value(s) from your provider, you should assume that you must have it; that would be my personal assumption. Whether you should use that as your primary key depends on what you do with this information. The columns you choose for clustering should be a separate discussion from those you choose as the primary key.

And the statement *"... which, on normal occasions I would regularely set to be DB auto generated ..."* is concerning. Blindly following a pattern is not a good idea. You should think about what your natural keys are and enforce them. You should intentionally choose your primary key. And you should make an effort to determine what your clustered index should be (especially since you only have one). When you determine "performance", you need to evaluate it based on how the table is used - types of queries, the content and frequency of DML statements, the quantity of rows that are added/modified/deleted over time, etc. Often, it makes sense to cluster on a date column since that tends to be a highly-used selection criterion.

I've worked with databases that pulled information from external "systems". Typically anything that has a significance from an external source requires that you keep the key values from that source. Why? Because you need the external system key to reconcile the data. Without it, you will find it difficult to determine the source of any difference. And your accountants and auditors might just want you to prove that your systems match - exactly. People tend to be REALLY picky about things like transactions.

So at this point, you have no justification to add your own synthetic key and use it as the primary key (or clustered index). So - don't. You need a reason to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I would not look at this issue in terms of data size. You should focus on the physical side of storing the data. If you implement a primary key on your table, it means it is stored as a balanced tree and that it is sorted by the values in the primary key column/columns.

Now, inserting a row using a surrogate key (meaning identity) means that you insert a new row at the end of the last data page, so you just add  some data at the end of the index. So if you generate keys with identity, you can fill the data pages of an index in an easy manner without fragmenting the index.

On the other hand, if you receive an integer from another system, you should assume it will be more or less random, so SQL Server will have to find space for a new record in some page, which might be full and that leads to page splits. It can result in long query execution time.

To sum up, performance will be better with identity values as an index. As to disk space... Well integers are not that big, are they?